# Custom configuration not getting reflected in applicationcontext.xml

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using custom configuration for my RabbitMQ connectivity. I'm connecting to multiple hosts.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/test_setting.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
...
<rabbit:connection-factory id="testConnectionFactory"
    addresses="${test.addresses}" 
    username="${test.username}"
    password="${test.password}" 
    virtual-host="${test.virtualhost}"
    connection-factory="rhb" />

<bean id="rhb" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
     <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="${test.connection.heartbeat}" />
</bean>
```

My property file looks like: test_setting.properties

```
test.queue=testQueue
test.virtualhost=/global_api
test.addresses=host1:5672,
               host2:5672
test.username=guest
test.password=guest
test.connection.heartbeat=60
test.consumer.concurrency=1
```

When i trigger my main class properties not getting replaced inside applicationcontext.xml in Spring. Thereby I am getting connection refused exception. 

Please note if I hard code the connection details everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ignore-unresolvable="true"`

It looks like the file is not being found - change that to false to see the error.

Also, turning on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` will provide a great deal of information about property resolution.

```
test.addresses=host1:5672,
               host2:5672
```

Properties have to be on one line (you can terminate a line with `\`) for continuation.

```
test.addresses=host1:5672, \
               host2:5672
```

Comment: It was my mistake. I had 2 properties with same name that was causing the issue. Thanks for the solution, enabling the debug logging helped me in identifying the cause.